# Regex in python / pandas causing strange end of line characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm just getting started with Pandas and am working on a domain cleanup tool. Essentially, I want to remove all subdomains & just retain the main domain + the tld.

The below works in ipython against a single domain, but I am struggling against a dataframe of multiple domains.

The script seems to work, but the regular expression results in the end of line characters (like below) being printed at the end of the domain (e.g. com\n1')

I'm not sure what these characters are - I've tried rstrip, but it hasn't worked. Can anyone advise what these characters are & how I can get rid of them to make the script work?

**OUTPUT**

```
['0          graph', 'facebook', 'com\n1              news', 'bbc', 'co', 'uk\n2
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

When I run the same in ipython, I get the below - I need the split to be the same when using a df column.

```
In [12]: re.split(r'\.(?!\d)', (str('domain.domain.com')))
Out[12]: ['domain', 'domain', 'com']
```

**INPUT**

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import re

In [3]: path = "Desktop/domains.csv"

In [4]: df = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter=',', header='infer')

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
                     Domain
0        graph.facebook.com
1            news.bbc.co.uk
2  news.more.news.bbc.co.uk
3       profile.username.co
4           offers.o2.co.uk
5     subdomain.pyspark.org
6       uds.data.domain.net

In [7]: for index, row in df.iterrows():
   ...:     tld = ['co.uk', 'com', 'org', 'co', 'net']
   ...:     index = re.split(r'\.(?!\d)', (str(df.Domain)))
   ...:     print(index)
   ...:     if str(index[len(index)-2]).rstrip()+'.'+ str(index[len(index)-1]).rstrip() in tld:
   ...:         print(str(index[len(index)-3])+'.'+str(index[len(index)-2])+'.'+ str(index[len(index)-1]))
   ...:     elif str(index[len(index)-1]) in tld:
   ...:         print(str(index[len(index)-2])+'.'+ str(index[len(index)-1]))
```

---

UPDATE

---

Thank you to everyone for the help so far.

The below now works exactly as expected, but, the outputs are all duplicated several times.

E.g. You can see that Facebook.com has been printed twice in the output list & I can't really understand why - can anyone advise?

**INPUT**

```
In [38]: for row in df.iterrows():
    ...:     tld = ['co.uk', 'com', 'org', 'co', 'net']
    ...:     index = df.Domain[df.Domain.str.strip().str.endswith(tuple(tld))].str.split('.').tolist()
    ...:     for x in index:
    ...:         if str(x[len(x)-2]).rstrip()+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]).rstrip() in tld:
    ...:             print(str(x[len(x)-3])+'.'+str(x[len(x)-2])+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]))
    ...:         elif str(x[len(x)-1]) in tld:
    ...:             print(str(x[len(x)-2])+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]))
    ...: 
    ...:                     
facebook.com
bbc.co.uk
bbc.co.uk
username.co
o2.co.uk
pyspark.org
domain.net
facebook.com
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: Hi sorry - I've added that now! In the list produced by the regex + split, I just need each element of the domain included, e.g. ['subdomain', 'facebook', 'com'] rather than the current  ['subdomain', 'facebook', 'com\n1]

Comment: What does that command do? the output is: KeyError: False

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-fda2b689d648> in <module>()
----> 1 df["result"=='']
      2

Comment: Try `df['Domain'].str.split('.')`. Is that you expected output?

Comment: Umm... can you not do something like: `df.Domain[df.Domain.str.strip().str.endswith(tuple(tld))].str.split('.').tolist() ` ?

Comment: Hi - thanks, that does produce the right result, but it prints the output 6 times, which is odd!, like this: 0             [graph, facebook, com]
1                [news, bbc, co, uk]
2    [news, more, news, bbc, co, uk]
3            [profile, username, co]
4               [offers, o2, co, uk]
5          [subdomain, pyspark, org]
6           [uds, data, domain, net]
Name: Domain, dtype: object
0             [graph, facebook, com]
1                [news, bbc, co, uk]
...

Comment: Yes, it will show the split for all the rows. I still don't understand what your expected output is. Do you only want to split for one value/row?

Comment: Hi there - thanks for all your help so far. It's very close now. I want to produce a split for every row of the excel, but only want to produce one output domain per row. As per the update to my main post (just added), I'm getting every domain repeated many times. I just want to see the 'clean' version of each domain in the file (each domain only appears once, in the file, so I only need one output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
In [5]: import pandas as pd
In [6]: import re
#Define the path of the file & generate the dataframe from it
In [7]: path = "Desktop/domains.csv"
In [8]: df = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter=',', header='infer')
#Show the dataframe to validate input is correct
In [9]: df
Out[10]:
                     Domain
0        graph.facebook.com
1            news.bbc.co.uk
2  news.more.news.bbc.co.uk
3       profile.username.co
4           offers.o2.co.uk
5     subdomain.pyspark.org
6       uds.data.domain.net

#Iterate through the rows of the dataframe. If the domain ends with anything in the TLD list, then split the domains at the '.' into a list
In [11]: for row in df.iterrows():
    ...:     tld = ['co.uk', 'com', 'org', 'co', 'net']
    ...:     index = df.Domain[df.Domain.str.strip().str.endswith(tuple(tld))].str.split('.').tolist()
    ...:
#Now, let's look at the output of index. It's a list of lists. So, if we select index[1]. we will get  ['news', 'bbc', 'co', 'uk']
In [12]: index
Out[12]:
[['graph', 'facebook', 'com'],
 ['news', 'bbc', 'co', 'uk'],
 ['news', 'more', 'news', 'bbc', 'co', 'uk'],
 ['profile', 'username', 'co'],
 ['offers', 'o2', 'co', 'uk'],
 ['subdomain', 'pyspark', 'org'],
 ['uds', 'data', 'domain', 'net']]

#We therefore need to iterate through each item of the lists
#So, we need to go through index[0][0] (the sub lists - to see the breakdown of each domain)
#Now we take the length of the list e.g. graph, facebook, com = length of 3
#as it's a zero'd index, we need to start at 0 and hence a list with a length of 3, has a range of 0-2
#so first, we check, is the last but one character + the last character in the TLD list (e.g. co.uk)
#if yes, we take the last 3 elements of the list, to produce 'bbc.co.uk'
#if no, we go through and check the last character & see if its in the list (e.g. com)
#if it is, we print the last 2 characters (e.g. facebook.com)
    ...: for x in index:
    ...:     if str(x[len(x)-2]).rstrip()+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]).rstrip() in tld:
    ...:         print(str(x[len(x)-3])+'.'+str(x[len(x)-2])+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]))
    ...:     elif str(x[len(x)-1]) in tld:
    ...:         print(str(x[len(x)-2])+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]))
    ...:

#and here is the ouput
facebook.com
bbc.co.uk
bbc.co.uk
username.co
o2.co.uk
pyspark.org
domain.net
```